# Dynamic Programming - 4 Keys Keyboard

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

> Imagine you have a special keyboard with the following keys:
>
> Key 1: (A): Print one 'A' on screen.
>
> Key 2: (Ctrl-A): Select the whole screen.
>
> Key 3: (Ctrl-C): Copy selection to buffer.
>
> Key 4: (Ctrl-V): Print buffer on screen appending it after what has
>   already been printed.
>
> Now, you can only press the keyboard for N times (with the above four
>   keys), find out the maximum numbers of 'A' you can print on screen.

**Example 1:**

Input: N = 3

Output: 3

Explanation: We can at most get 3 A's on screen by pressing following key sequence: `A, A, A`

**Example 2:**
Input: N = 7

Output: 9

Explanation: We can at most get 9 A's on screen by pressing following key sequence: `A, A, A, Ctrl A, Ctrl C, Ctrl V, Ctrl V`

**(DISCLAIMER: I DON'T WANT TO HEAR A DIFFERENT SOLUTION. I just want to understand what I'm missing and how to fix it.)**

Here's my current (incorrect) solution (explanation below):

```
class Solution:
    def maxA(self, N):
        screen = [0] * N
        screen[0] = 1
        applied_clipboard = clipboard = select = 0        
        for i in range(1, N):
            if i < 3:
                screen[i] = screen[i-1] + 1
            else:
                screen[i] = max(screen[i-3] + clipboard, screen[i-1] + 1, screen[i-1] + applied_clipboard)

                if screen[i] == screen[i-3] + clipboard:
                    applied_clipboard = clipboard

            select, clipboard = max(select, screen[i-1]), max(clipboard, select)
        return screen[-1]
```

There are a few pieces of state that I'm tracking, as you can see in the above code. The states are:

1. How many characters have I selected?
2. How many characters have I printed onto the screen?
3. How many characters are in my clipboard?
4. What's the latest clipboard that I've actually applied?

With these pieces of state, I believe I can make the optimal decision at each step.

However, my code is incorrect. For the input of `N = 11`, my code returns `27`, and the correct value is `27`. However, for `N=9` and `N=10`, the correct values are `16` and `20` (respectively), but I get `15` and `18` (respectively).

Does anyone see the bug in the way I'm updating state?

**EDIT. Responding to the existing answers:** 
I understand that my state update may be incomplete, but the question is where. My idea here was to keep every piece of state maximized, as there's a separate series of decisions to maximize each piece of state. Then, use all that information to update the state in the following iteration.

Rewrote my code to retain the state of each piece.

```
class Solution:
    def maxA(self, N):
        screen = [0] * N
        screen[0] = 1
        applied_clipboard, clipboard, select = [[0] * N for _ in range(3)]

        for i in range(1, N):
            if i < 3:
                screen[i] = screen[i-1] + 1
            else:
                screen[i] = max(screen[i-3] + clipboard[i-1], screen[i-1] + 1, screen[i-1] + applied_clipboard[i-1])

                if screen[i] == screen[i-3] + clipboard[i-1]:
                    applied_clipboard[i] = clipboard[i-1]
                else:
                    applied_clipboard[i] = applied_clipboard[i-1]

            select[i] = max(select[i-1], screen[i-1])
            clipboard[i] = max(clipboard[i-1], select[i-1])

        print('screen', screen)
        print('clipboard', clipboard)
        print('applied', applied_clipboard)
        return screen[-1]
```

I think what I'm confusing here is how to retain what clipboard value has been applied (`applied_clipboard`) vs what the max clipboard state is. But I need to differentiate between the two as it affects the recurrence relationship.

Thanks to `user3386109` for leading me to see that:

- The correct series of steps to take for `N=9` is `AAAASCVVV` (16 total A's)
- My code, for `N=9`, outputs `AAASCVVVV` (15 total A's).

where s = select, c = copy, and v = paste.

Comment: What do you mean by your "DISCLAIMER"? Maybe a different solution would be easier to read and less prone to bugs. Maybe your solution is just wrong so a "different" correct solution is required.

Comment: When you get to a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful things and accept your favourite answer (even if you have to write it yourself), so Stack Overflow can properly archive the question.

Answer (score 2):

The bug, quite simply, is that the code is maximizing the number of 'A's on the screen at each step. If you `print screen` at the end of the function when `N` is 9, you'll see this:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 15]
```

Notice that when `N` is 6, the maximum number of 'A's on the screen is 6. That can be accomplished three different ways:

```
AAAAAA
AAscvv
AAAscv
```

where s = select, c = copy, and v = paste.

However, when `N` is 9 the correct answer is

```
AAAAscvvv
```

As you can see, after 6 key presses, the number of 'A's on the screen is only 4, not 6. So maximizing the number of 'A's on the screen at each step does not give the right answer.

Comment: I get that, and that's in line with what @Prune said as well, but it's not clear to me where I'm doing this incorrectly. The idea behind DP is to maintain all pieces of state independently for an `(i-1)` step, in order to make the optimal decision for each of these pieces of state at the `(ith)` step. Because I'm updating my clipboard state correctly, where am I shorting incorrect state? `screen[i]` *should* be optimal for any value of `[i]`, but the other pieces of state should allow this to update accordingly.

Comment: Something must be incorrect in my state updating (or its just incomplete as Prune suggested) for this to be the result.

Comment: For `N=9`, here are the states of each piece: 

`screen [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 12, 15]` | 
`clipboard [0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9]`|
`applied [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3]`|

Interesting, clipboard[5] is in fact `4` as you suggest

Comment: @segue_segway I'm not sure what the `clipboard` values actually represent. The `applied` values make perfect sense though. Given that the first six key presses were `AAAscv`, you can see that on the sixth keypress, you pasted 3 'A's from the buffer. The remaining three keypresses were `vvv` and each one pasted 3 'A's.

Comment: Perhaps the `clipboard` values represent the maximum number of 'A's that can be in the buffer at any point. But your algorithm doesn't seem to do anything with that information.

Comment: In case it's of interest, it looks like the behaviour of the data does offer an `O(n)` algorithm (posted something).

Comment: @גלעדברקן I tried your new solution and it does seem to work. But it seems to me that the "early out" in the code requires some sort of proof. The algorithm outlined in Prune's answer is also O(n), since with three attributes, there are at most 6 dominating states. So for each iteration, the code computes 24 possible new states (six old states * four possible actions), and selects at most 6 dominating states from those 24. The result is an O(n) algorithm.

Comment: @גלעדברקן Agreed. And I think I have some insight into that. I examined the logarithmic efficiency of various key sequences. Here's what I found. The sequence `scv` requires k=3 key presses, and doubles the number of A's on the screen, m=2. So the logarithmic efficiency  `ln(m) / k` is 0.231.  `scvv` has k=4 and m=3, efficiency 0.275. `scvvv` is 0.277. `scvvvv` is 0.268. `scvvvvv` is 0.256. So peak efficiency is achieved either by tripling with `scvv` or quadrupling with `scvvv`.  Which means the optimal screen to select is typically three or four states back.

Comment: Thanks, I was just going to suggest looking into some numerical thing that becomes apparent with larger screens. It seems to settle on 6-back pretty quickly if I'm not mistaken, but I didn't examine very far up.

Answer (score 2):

One way to think of it can be that our solution must end with a `paste` since clearly we wouldn't want to waste presses by ending with a `select` or `copy`. Then we can assume that the screen state we'd like to choose to paste from is optimal (otherwise, why would we paste from it?).

Let `f(n)` represent the maximum number of `A`s possible to output. Then we could choose to have repeatedly applied any screen state back three presses or more. For example, on the 7th press, we can look back and say: to repeat screen state 4 (which is just 4) we need 3 presses so repeating from 4 would offer our record for 7, 4 + 4 = 8 `A`s. If we were to try repeating from 3, we'd need 3 presses for 1 repetition, bringing us to 6, and we can still have 1 more so 3 + 2*3 = 9. So repeatedly applying screen state 3, offers the record for 7 nine `A`s, which is the best. For any `0 < j < i-3`, we can get `1 + i - (j + 3) + 1` or `i - j - 1` times the `j`th screen state.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(n) {
  const m = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].concat(
    new Array(Math.max(n-6,0)).fill(0));

  for (let i=7; i<=n; i++)
    for (let j=1; j<=i-3; j++)
      m[i] = Math.max(m[i], m[j]*(i-j-1));

  console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
  return m[n];
}

console.log(4, f(4));
console.log(7, f(7));
console.log(9, f(9));
console.log(10, f(10));
console.log(11, f(11));
```

Examining the data, I found that the optimal screen state to copy from seems consistently very close to `n` (within 6 states back), and seems consistently convex when traversing backwards, which means we can optimize by traversing backwards and looking for a downward change.

If this behaviour is consistent it would mean the algorithm has `O(n)` complexity.

```js
function f(n) {
  const m = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6].concat(
    new Array(Math.max(n-6,0)).fill(0));

  for (let i=7; i<=n; i++){
    let prev = 0;
    for (let j=i-3; j>0; j--){
      let curr = m[j]*(i-j-1);
      if (curr < prev){
        console.log(`Early exit. n: ${n}, i: ${i}, j: ${j}`);
        break;
      }
      prev = curr;
      m[i] = Math.max(m[i], curr);
    }
  }

  console.log(JSON.stringify(m));
  return m[n];
}

console.log(50, f(50));
```

Answer (score 1):

As best I can see (now that I've altered the code to be runnable), you're updating things fine.  I suspect that the problem is with an incomplete state update.  Unfortunately, I think that your implementation is correct, but your algorithm is wrong.

I *think* your problem is with the `screen` update every iteration short-circuiting your long-term goals.  At each iteration, you process the choices as if this key-press must be your last.  As a result, you sometimes forego a clipboard with greater potential, and update with only what gets you the most `A`s for this step.

You need to maintain multiple useful states for each step: not only the greatest screen display, but also the potential of a wealthy clipboard.

**UPDATE**
I think we're together in our thinking now.  You need to have multiple states -- partial solutions -- stored for each quantity of keystrokes.  This is not a straightforward recurrence relation: it's more of a quantum state.

For instance, at 7 keystrokes, you need to represent at least two states.

- Resulting from AAAASCV, you have 8 `A`s on the screen, 4 in the clipboard.  (8, 4)
- Resulting from AAASCVV, you have 9 `A`s on the screen, 3 in the clipboard.  (9, 3)

Your current algorithm allows only one value each for `screen` and `clipboard` at each quantity of keystrokes.  It keeps only the solution with the best short-term result.  It misses that (8,4) will be the better stepping-stone to 9 and 10 keystrokes.

You need to keep all of the pairs that are not dominated at each step.  state G "dominates" state H iff `G(screen) >= H(screen)` **and** `G(clipboard) >= H(clipboard)`.

---

Also note that you need to have a lesser-used element in your state: what is currently selected.  For instance, consider the case (for illustration) of the two above states, one stroke (paste) further along, and one more that "planned ahead":

```
scr   clip   sel
12      4     0          Nothing selected
12      3     0          Nothing selected
 9      3     9          Stopped at 9 A's and did a select-copy
```

This third state will immediately outstrip the first two for another two steps.

Comment: So the `clipboard` state is what I'm using to establish a wealthy clipboard, and that is updated on every iteration. Only applied_clipboard isn't, which is okay because I should only updated applied_clipboard when it's been applied. Right?

Comment: The state for `screen` and `clipboard` should be independently optimized (there are a separate series of decisions to optimize `screen` and `clipboard`). There's why I have `clipboard = max(clipboard, select)`. Where's the short-circuit?

Comment: Your state updating is incomplete, in that the screen and clipboard are *not* independent.  Your full state is a tuple of screen and clipboard; you need to carry the *pair* along the path of solution.

Comment: Try building a game tree on paper for the various active paths; you should see the difference there between the optimum path to 9 and 10, as opposed to what your program does.  Do you see how the information needs to be linked to get back to the correct path?

Comment: Yeah, I edited my original question to include the steps my program outputs for `N = 9` vs what the correct output for `N=9` is. But I also want to point out that, as expected, the code frequently opts to choose: `max(screen[i-3] + clipboard[i-1])`, meaning it revisits previous values depending on whether clipboard has become high enough. So I'm still stumped on how to fix this..

Comment: The recurrence relationship is: if I knew the series of decisions that leads me to have the optimal values at iteration `i-1` for `screen` and `clipboard`, then I can tell you what the optimal value is for `screen[i]`. I still think I'm not handling the notion of `applied_clipboard` correctly, meaning I don't `revisit` this value. It stays in step with clipboard, but am not sure how to account for this otherwise. I need a way to differentiate between paying the cost for something in the clipboard, and reapplying it once I've decided to pay the cost.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the correct approach. Multiple competing states must be stored at each step. Only those states that are dominated in all categories can be discarded.